# I store a variable using JWT at backend succesfully but when I try to use it returns "undefined"

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, express, jwt

I successfully send a customer id from frontend to the backend. When I check payload, I have seen "customer_id". But when I try to use it in a app.post function "customer_id" returns undefined. I decode token using at jwt.io token seems correct

Info ; i get customer id in `app.post('/api/admin-dashboard')`. I try to use it in `app.post('/api/admin-dashboard/add-device')`

I created something like this ;

I am sending to "dbService" and get response succesfully.

```
onCustomerSelected(event: any) {
    this.selectedCustomerId = event.value;
    localStorage.setItem('selectedCustomerId', this.selectedCustomerId.toString());

    this.dbService.sendCustomerId(this.selectedCustomerId).subscribe({

      next: (response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', response.token);
        console.log('Customer ID sent to backend successfully:', response);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('Error sending customer ID to backend:', error);
      }
    });  
    console.log(this.selectedCustomerId);
  }
```

In db service file ;

```
sendCustomerId(customerId: string): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      })
    };
    return this.http.post<any>(this.apiUrl + "/admin-dashboard", { customer_id: customerId }, httpOptions);
  }
```

Lastly in backend file I store it using jwt.sign like this ;

```
app.post('/api/admin-dashboard', authenticateToken ,(req, res) => {
  const customerId = req.body.customer_id;
  console.log('Received customer ID:', customerId);
  
  
  const token = jwt.sign({ customerId: customerId }, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
  res.json({ message: 'Received customer ID successfully', token });
});
```

I verify token using middleware.js file ;

```
const secretKey = 'asdASD'; function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

    jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err, user) => {

        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        req.user = user;
        console.log(user)
        next();

    });
}
```

But when I try to use req.user.customerId in `app.post('/api/add-device')` it returns undefined.

Comment: You set 'jwtToken' in localstorage but get 'token'. Try getting 'jwtToken'

Comment: No problem, classic misstake i've done many times myself! Did you get it to work?

Comment: Actually no... I am trying to fix jwt malformed error right now. I couldnt see where is the problem